# NASM invalid address behaviour?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have an array named `a` and a constant named n that I'm trying to address as a two-dimensional array with the following line: `mov al, [a+ebx*n+esi]`
The problem is that if `n` is even (`n equ 4`), it works perfectly, but if `n` is odd (`n equ 3`) the compiler gives "error: invalid effective address". I could understand if it worked or failed in **both** cases, but I cannot understand why they are working differently.

Compiler: NASM
Linker: GCC (minGW for Windows)
IDE: SASM

The program:

```
    %include "io.inc"

section .data
a    db    1, 2, 3, 4
     db    5, 6, 7, 9
     db    9, 10, 11, 12
     db    13, 14, 15, 16
n    equ   4

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ; write your code here
    ;
    ; get upper limit
    xor    eax, eax
    mov    edi, n
    ;
    ; get last column
    mov    esi, n-1
    xor    ebx, ebx
    xor    edx, edx ; count in DL
    xor    ecx, ecx ; sum in CX
    mov    dh, 3
cycle:
    xor    ah, ah
    mov    al, [a+ebx*n+esi]
    div    dh
    cmp    ah, 0
    jne    afteradd
    add    cl, [a+ebx*n+esi]
    add    dl, 1
afteradd:
    add    ebx, 1
    cmp    ebx, edi
    jl     cycle
solve:
    mov    ax, cx
    div    dl       ; среднее арифметическое будет в AL
aftercycle:
    xor    eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: Using 3*ebx = "push ebx" , "lea ebx, [ebx+ebx*2]" , " mov al,[ebx+esi+a]", ..... "add cl,[ebx+esi+a]", ..... , afteradd: "pop ebx", "add ebx,1"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset part of an address is given on the form `base + index*scale + displacement`. There are only certain values that are allowed for the `scale` part of the offset. These are `1` (the default), `2`, `4` and `8`.

This is described in [Intel's Software Developers Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Vol 1 (the section named *Specifying an Offset*):

> The offset part of a memory address can be specified directly as a static value (called a **displacement**) or through
>   an address computation made up of one or more of the following components:
>   • **Displacement** — An 8-, 16-, or 32-bit value.
>   • **Base** — The value in a general-purpose register.
>   • **Index** — The value in a general-purpose register.
>   • **Scale factor** — A value of 2, 4, or 8 that is multiplied by the index value.

(The above quote is for 32-bit mode, but the same limitation on the scale factor applies in 64-bit mode)

Comment: (Precisely the above quote is additional for the 16-bit mode together with using operandsize/addresssize prefixes for 80386+.)